# How to safely and efficiently connect to a MongoDB replicaset instance with the C# Driver

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB with the C# driver and am wondering what is the most efficient yet safe way to create connections to the database.

#### Thread Safety

According to the Mongo DB C# driver documentation the [MongoClient, MongoServer, MongoDatabase, MongoCollection and MongoGridFS classes are thread safe](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#thread-safety). Does this mean I can have a singleton instance of `MongoClient` or `MongoDatabase`?

The documentation also states that [a connection pool is used for `MongoClient`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#mongoclient-class), so the management of connections to MongoDB is abstracted from the `MongoClient` class anyway.

#### Example Scenario

Let's say I have three MongoDB instances in my replicaset; so I create `MongoClient` and `MongoDatabase` objects based upon the three server addresses for these instances. Can I create a static singleton for the database and client objects and use them across multiple requests simultaneously? What if one of the instances dies; if I cache the Mongo objects, how can I make sure this scenario is dealt with safely?

Answer (score 1):

In my project I'm using a singleton MongoClient only, then get MongoServer and other stuff from MongoClient.
This is because what you said, the connection pool is in the MongoClient, I definitely don't want more than one connection pool. and here's what the [document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#mongoclient-class) says:

> When you are connecting to a replica set you will still use only one
>   instance of MongoClient, which represents the replica set as a whole.
>   The driver automatically finds all the members of the replica set and
>   identifies the current primary.

Actually the MongoClient is added to C# driver since 1.7, to represent the whole replica set and handle failover, load balancing stuff. Because MongoServer doesn't have the ability to to that. Thus you shouldn't cache MongoServer because once a server is offline you can't know it.

EDIT: Just had a look at the source code. I may have made a mistake. The MongoClient doesn't handle connection pool. the MongoServer does (at least until driver 1.7, haven't looked at the latest driver source yet). This makes sense because MongoServer represents a real Mongo instance. And one connection pool stores connections only to that server.